# Get first and last inovice # in every date

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order

I am trying to show invoices for every single day, so for that purpose I used group by on created date and sum on subtotal. This is how I done it :

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();

$orders->getSelect()
       ->columns(array(
            'total_sales' => 'SUM(subtotal)',
       ))
      ->group('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y")');
```

Its working, but I also want to get the Invoice # from and Invoice # to for every date. Is it possible to do it with single query ?

Comment: Don't understand what you're asking, please explain in detail.

Comment: How to get first and last record number using group by day ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK solved, it was an easy one

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();

$orders->getSelect()
        ->columns(array(
            'total_sales' => 'SUM(subtotal)',
            'invoice_from' => 'MIN(increment_id)',
            'invoice_to'  => 'MAX(increment_id)',
        ))
       ->group('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%y")');
```

Comment: got help from sql community here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554262/get-first-and-last-record-number-in-every-date-exists-in-table

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to get invoice between two date

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();
$orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
'from' => 'datefrom',
'to' => 'dateto',
));
```

Comment: Im trying to get 1st and last invoice number for every date (for which record exists obviously), getting invoices between 2 dates is a bit different

Comment: did you try `$_collection->getFirstItem()` and `$_collection->getLastItem()`

Comment: It will print the first and last record of collection, not of every day/date

Answer (score 2):

Try this code maybe helpful

//Set your start and end date

```
$start_date = '2015-12-30';
    $end_date = '2016-01-01';

    while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        $startdates = $start_date;
        $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));

        //$addoneday = strtotime("+1 day");
        $orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order_invoice")->getCollection();
        $orders->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from' => $startdates,
            'to' => $start_date,
        ));

        echo "<pre>";
        echo $startdates.' First invoice';
        print_r($orders->getFirstItem()->getData());
        echo "<br>";
        echo $startdates. 'Last invoice';
        print_r($orders->getLastItem()->getData());
    }
```

Comment: It will print the first and last record of collection, not of every date

Comment: Hi @Ahmed i have change my code please try again

Comment: actually I don't want to load the collection more than 1 time :|

Comment: please check the answer I just added